# Rhino.Commons and it won't compile

Tags: c#, rhino-commons

I get this very strange error message when trying to use Rhino.Commons with my asp.net mvc application.

```
Error   3   'Rhino.Commons.Repository<Web.Models.Poll>.FindAll()' is not supported by the language  C:\frank\dev\SampleApplication\Web\Models\Repositories\IPollRepository.cs   15  20  Web
```

Someone got any experience with this error?

Answer (score 0):

try [this](http://ddkonline.blogspot.com/2008/02/fixing-design-time-exception-methodname.html), seems promising. ie try to update your referenced dll for all your projects.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same message "is not supported by the language" for several methods and constructors.

The solution for me was to clean the solution and rebuild everything.